# what is the difference with Array.prototype.splice and arr.splice in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

code:（vue2.0, vue-router）

```
<template>
 <a v-for="apiItem in allApis" href="#"></a>
</template>
<script>
  computed: mapGetters([
    'allApis'
  ]),
</script>
```

and in `store/modules`

```
const mutations {
  myMutation(state) {
    state.apis.splice(0, 1) // A
    //Array.prototype.splice.call(state.apis, 0, 1); //B
  }
}
const getter = {
  allApis: (state) => {
    return state.apis
  }
}
export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

the `line A` will change the `allApis` and update the view

but the `line B` will not change the `allApi` and update the view;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `state.apis.splice(0, 1)` will work, as Vue intercept mutating methods and emit events as you can see here in the [code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ae93d2bef8e20402ae3501aa5cdcf14b0ee19c12/src/core/observer/array.js#L23).

```
const arrayProto = Array.prototype
export const arrayMethods = Object.create(arrayProto)
/**
 * Intercept mutating methods and emit events
 */
;[
  'push',
  'pop',
  'shift',
  'unshift',
  'splice',
  'sort',
  'reverse'
]
.forEach(function (method) {
  // cache original method
  const original = arrayProto[method]
```

As you see in the source code: `arrayMethods` are original Array prototype methods which are being overwritten to give you reactivity functionality of vue, so using `Array.prototype` misses the behavior vue defines.

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html):

> Vue wraps an observed array’s mutation methods so they will also trigger view updates.

Comment: You're right but aware or not, you're missing an important point that in the source code you are referring, `export const arrayMethods = Object.create(arrayProto)` is creating a new prototype for arrays, so using `Array.prototype` misses the behavior vue defines.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 Yes, that's what I am trying to point out here, that you get this additional functionality with these functions which you don't get in `Array.prototype`, may be I am not that clear in that answer, Will add it explicitly.